# Screen Recording with both headphone & system audio

Tags: audio, web-applications, screen-recording

I am trying to build a **web-application** with the functionality of screen-recording with system audio + headphone-mic audio being captured in the saved video.

I have been thoroughly googling on a solution for this, however my findings show multiple browser solutions where the above works so long as headphones are **NOT** connected, meaning the microphone input is coming from the system rather than headset.

In the case that you connect headphones, all of these solutions capture the screen without video-audio, and the microphone audio from my headset. So to re-clarify on this, it should have recorded video-audio from the video being played whilst recording, and the headset-mic audio also.

This is thoroughly available in native applications, however I am searching for a way to do this on a **browser**.

If there are no solutions for this currently that anybody knows of, some insight on the limitations around developing this would also really help, thank you.

Comment: I believe, if you have a script that records screen sharing and another script records just audio (output from media + mic), run both at same time. After that merge both the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser manages the media input being received in the selected tab/window

To receive media input, you need to ensure you have the checkbox `Share Audio` in the image below **checked**. However this will only record media-audio being played in your headphones, when it comes to receiving microphone audio, the opposite must be done i.e the checkbox should be **unchecked**, or merge the microphone audio separately on saving the recorded video

https://slack-files.com/T1JA07M6W-F0297CM7F32-89e7407216

Answer (score 1):

1. create two `const`, one retrieving on-screen video, other retrieving audio media:

```
const DISPLAY_STREAM = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: {cursor: "motion"}, audio: {'echoCancellation': true}}); // retrieving screen-media
        
const VOICE_STREAM = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: {'echoCancellation': true}, video: false }); // retrieving microphone-media
```

2. Use AudioContext to retrieve audio sources from `getUserMedia()` and `getDisplayMedia()` separately:

```
const AUDIO_CONTEXT = new AudioContext();

const MEDIA_AUDIO = AUDIO_CONTEXT.createMediaStreamSource(DISPLAY_STREAM); // passing source of on-screen audio
            
const MIC_AUDIO = AUDIO_CONTEXT.createMediaStreamSource(VOICE_STREAM); // passing source of microphone audio
```

3. Use the method below to create a new audio source which will be used as as the merger or merged version of audio, then passing audios into the merger:

```
const AUDIO_MERGER = AUDIO_CONTEXT.createMediaStreamDestination(); // audio merger

MEDIA_AUDIO.connect(AUDIO_MERGER); // passing media-audio to merger
MIC_AUDIO.connect(AUDIO_MERGER); // passing  microphone-audio to merger
```

4. Finally, connect the merged-audio and video together into one array to form a track, and pass it to the MediaStreamer:

```
const TRACKS = [...DISPLAY_STREAM.getVideoTracks(), ...AUDIO_MERGER.stream.getTracks()] // connecting on-screen video with merged-audio
stream = new MediaStream(TRACKS);
```